# Verben mit 2 Akkusativ-Ergänzungen

Tags: grammar, verb

Heute, während des Unterrichts, lernte ich einige Verben mit 2 Akkusativ-Ergänzungen, diese sind:

> kosten
>
> lehren
>
> nennen
>
> abfragen
>
> abhören

Ich frage mich jedoch, ob es auch andere Verben mit 2 Akkusativ-Ergänzungen gibt?. Zum Beispiel, hat das Verb *fragen* 2 Akkusativ-Ergänzungen?, Ich glaube ja, aber ich bin nicht sicher!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ja, *fragen* ist tatsächlich auch ein solches Verb:

> Kannst du mich nicht etwas Leichteres fragen?

Ansonsten dürfte die Liste bereits ziemlich vollständig sein, denn solche Verben sind sehr selten; und sie werden noch seltener, weil in der Umgangssprache eines von ihnen im Aussterben begriffen ist (*lehren* wird ersetzt durch *beibringen*) und ansonsten häufig schon das eine Objekt in den Dativ gesetzt wird:

> Das hätte ihm fast das Leben gekostet.

(Bitte nicht im Deutschunterricht nachmachen! :-))

---

Allerdings gehört *nennen* eigentlich nicht so richtig in den gleichen Topf wie die anderen Verben, denn bei den beiden Akkusativergänzungen von *nennen* handelt es sich um einen sogenannten Gleichsetzungsakkusativ: Der eine Begriff wird als dem anderen gleich dargestellt; es sind also keine unabhängigen Objekte. Hier gibt es noch ein paar Verben, die die gleiche Grundbedeutung wie *nennen* haben: *schimpfen*, *schelten* (altertümlich), *heißen* (altertümlich).

> Sie nannte/schimpfte/schalt/hieß ihn einen Lügner.

Comment: Danke schön! Ich habe andere Frage, mit diesen Verben ist ein von 2 Akk.-Ergänzungen das Personalpronomen (in Akk.), nicht wahr?

Comment: @mle: Ich bin nicht ganz sicher, was die Frage ist; es können jedenfalls alle Satzteile Nicht-Pronomina sein: _Die Reparatur hat den Eigentümer einen Hunderter gekostet._ _Ein Esel nennt den anderen (ein) Langohr._

Comment: ich habe verstanden, du hast mir geantwortet ;) Danke!

Comment: Die Aussage zu „kosten“ mag ich nicht wahr haben. Warum sollte das sagen, wer nicht auch „*Das Handy hat mir 300€ gekostet“ sagt?

Comment: @mle und es können auch beide Pronomen sein: Ich hab **ihn es** gefragt.

Comment: "kosten" fällt doch auch in gleiche Kategorie wie "nennen": vgl "Das kostet dich" und "Das kostet das Leben".

Comment: @Carsten Schultz: Ich verstehe den Einwand nicht. Natürlich wird auch dein Satz gesagt.

Comment: @Em1: Auch was du sagen willst, ist mir nicht klar.

Comment: "Frag mich" und "Frag etwas Leichteres" oder kombiniert "Frag mich etwas Leichteres" -> Aber keine Abhängigkeit, beide Teilsätze in Ordnung ## "Nenn mich" und "Nenn einen Esel" oder kombiniert "Nenn mich einen Esel" -> Abhängigkeit, Teilsätze nicht akzeptabel ## "Kostet dich" und "Kostet das Leben" oder kombiniert "Kostet dich das Leben" -> Abhängigkeit ++++ Mein Punkt ist, dass Nennen und Kosten in die gleiche Kategorie gehören.

Comment: @Em1: Häh? Wenn du die Verben danach einteilen willst, ob man Ergänzungen nach Belieben weglassen kann, dann sind sicher _nennen_ und _kosten_ näher beieinander; aber eine sinnvolle Kategorisierung scheint mir das nicht. Wenn ich nach Passivierbarkeit gruppiere, gehören _fragen_ und _nennen_ zusammen und _kosten_ ist woanders.

Comment: In dem Zusammenhang übrigens interessant, daß der (doppelte) Gleichsetzungsakkusativ zum (doppelten) Gleichsetzungsnominativ wird, in den anderen Fällen aber nur einer der Akkusative umgewandelt wird: *Er wird ein Esel genannt. Er wird etwas Leichteres gefragt.*

Comment: You certainly got a point there. Ich sollte mir angewöhnen, das Passiv auch mal zu beachten.